# Can we create an NSManagedObject outside it's context?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode4

Say I have a program. The program has a property called currentLocation.

Well when I construct currentLocation, if I add that to the context, that means I will end up keep adding new and new currentLocation object in the context?

Can I create currentLocation object outside it's context?

Or what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the changes are committed until you save. If you do not want to save something, you can always rollback.

Comment: But deleting previously created currentLocation is a hassle

Comment: Why is deleting a hassle? As I understand it, no `NSManagedObject` can be created outside the context. I am assuming you are storying Locations in core data and you want to add the current location to that data set?